# Proving that there exists a prime, p, between n! and n!+n iff p=n!+1

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

I have a conjecture (I believe this is not sophisticated enough to be a theorem) that there exists a prime, p, between n! and (n!+n) iff p=n!+1. I've tried a direct proof and a proof by contradiction without success. I then tried a proof by induction and this is the furthest I have gotten:

[image]

Can anyone hint at how I can complete this proof by induction or how to begin and proceed a direct proof?

(Sorry I couldn't use LaTeX, and also by p=n+1 I meant to say p=n!+, and this applies in all other places too)

Comment: What exactly do you mean $n! < p < n!+n$ where $p = n+1$? Clearly, $n!>p = n+1$ for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Your time would be better spent looking for a counterexample. :)

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me because $p=n+1$ can't be between $n!$ and $n!+n$.  Do you mean to say that "$n+1$ is prime iff there exists a prime between $n!$ and $n!+n$"?  It is likely that this is false.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you *mean* to prove is

> There is a prime between $n!$ and $n!+n$ if and only if $n!+1$ is prime.

Direct induction on $n$ doesn't really feel like a promising way to show this.

Instead, I would argue directly that $n!+1$ is the only number between $n!$ and $n!+n$ (inclusive) that has a chance of being prime, unless $n$ is trivially small:

Certainly $n!$ is composite (unless $n\le 2$), and $n!+2$ through $n!+n$ are also easily seen to be composite. So the only way there can exist a prime in your range is if $n!+1$ is prime.

This argument doesn't cover the cases $n=1,2$, but we can verify explicitly in this cases that the two sides of the claim have the same truth value:

- There is a prime between $1!$ and $1!+1$ (namely $2$), and $1!+1$ is prime.
- There is a prime between $2!$ and $2!+1$ (namely $2$), and $2!+1$ is prime.

On the other hand the claim fails for $n=0$:

- There **is no** prime between $0!=1$ and $0!+0=1$ (because $1$ is not a prime), yet $0!+1=2$ *is* a prime.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean be "$n!+2$ through $n!+n$ are also easily seen to be composite"? Do you mean that $n!+2$ and $n!+n$ are both composite or $n!+2, n!+4, n!+6,...n!+n$ are all composite?

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosen: I mean that $n!+2 , n!+3, n!+4, \ldots, n!+n$ are all composite -- namely, $n!+k$ is a non-trivial multiple of $k$ if $2\le k\le n$.